# SSRS report error generated but don't know why - BC30311 value of type error cannot be converted to String

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that I'm executing to create a drill-down report in SSRS. In my expression where this error is getting generated I have the following defined for a specific column value:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!RN) AND Fields!TermType = "New", Fields!WrittenPremium.Value, 0)
```

The Fields!WrittenPremium.Value is a MONEY datatype from SQL Server 2017 and the error shows the following:

```
The Value expression for the textrun "WrittenPremium.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30311] Value of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field' cannot be converted to 'String'.
```

I'm not sure why this conversion error is being generated and could use any help/direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the value property, not just the field. So a simple change to ....

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!RN.Value) AND Fields!TermType.Value = "New", Fields!WrittenPremium.Value, 0)
```

... should work.

Comment: Alan, thank you so much.  I feel pretty stupid.  Appreciate you taking time to look at this.

Comment: :) I've been doing this for more years than I care to remember and I still make that mistake every now and then.

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks.